# No Android connected device found, and no emulators could be started automatically | Visual studio Code

Tags: android, json, visual-studio-code

Am trying to run this android app on visual code using yarn android and i get this error

**`No Android connected device found, and no emulators could be started automatically. Please connect a device or create an emulator (https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/android-studio-emulator). Then follow the instructions here to enable USB debugging: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options. If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory.`
**
i'v tried everything i still get the same error

So Can someone help me troubleshoot and resolve the error I'm encountering while running this project in Visual Studio Code

[I get this when i yarn andoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybU4C.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.